# Codeigniter REQUEST_URI gets wrong value when app loaded from Internet

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, nginx, url-routing

I've installed latest Apache, PHP7 and codeigniter in a Ubuntu 17.04 server. I've assigned it a local IP, let's say *10.20.30.40* .
**This codeigniter app should work locally and also should work from outside (internet)**. 
There is also an intermediary nginx server (which I cannot access) that redirects everything from outside (Internet) to my server, so I've made some test and debugging with xdebug:

#### Locally

http://10.20.30.40/ciapp/index.php/test
works fine

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = string '/ciapp/index.php/test'
```

#### From Internet

http://www.subdomain.company.xxx/ciapp/index.php/test
does not work (it throws the codeigniter 404 page)

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = string '//ciapp/index.php/test'
```

(note the double slash preceding)

#### Also, I've tested the following

http://10.20.30.40//ciapp/index.php/test
(note the double slash on purpose) **didn't work, got the CI's 404**

*Is there something I could do with REQUEST_URI so it works from outside? Or maybe it is another problem...?*

PS: config suggested elsewhere:

```
$config['base_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == '10.20.30.40' ? 'http://10.20.30.40/ciapp/' : 'http://www.subdomain.company.xxx/ciapp/';
```

Comment: Is your local webserver running under windows and your live server running on linux by chance?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw codeigniter is installed in an Ubuntu server with static ip. The local url points to this server, and the live url also points to this Ubuntu server, with the difference that only the incoming traffic from internet is treated by another server (don't know OS) with nginx

Comment: Check PHP and Apache logs first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally solved by setting uri_protocol = PATH_INFO**

**file:** application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == '10.20.30.40' ? 'http://10.20.30.40/ci/' : 'http://www.subdomain.company.xxx/ciapp/'; 
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

**file:** .htaccess (to remove index.php from url)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now it is working perfect locally and loading from Internet

Answer (score 0):

Try base url as

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = "$root";
```

Comment: Hi @hrishi I got it working before checking your reply. Will try it anyway. Thanks

Comment: your solution works but only having $config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO'; so that seems to be the solution, PATH_INFO